A short novel in French about a computer able to analyse a text to extract its essential meaning. Not Asimov's "Foundation"
I read this rather short novel more than 40 years ago. It was in French, in a slim paperback, definitely the original, not a translation.
It was about a computer that was able to analyse written text (or even speech, though of course speech might have needed to be typed in order to be inserted) and extract its meaning. Also able to construct a text on any topic from diverse sources of information. Essentially, just ChatGPT. Artificial intelligence.
Now, of course, for a computer, neither "understanding and analysing text" nor "writing" is SF anymore, but more than 40 years ago, it was !
A very similar computer is mentioned, as early as 1942, in Asimov's "Foundation", IIRC in The Encyclopedists, when an imperial envoy makes a big speech meant to reassure the people of the Foundation that the Empire will protect them from the four Kingdoms, especially Anacreon. The whole speech is reduced to absolutely nothing when analysed by the computer. But if it is a similar machine, it is definitely not the same story.
My story was probably written long after 1942, in the 60's or 70's, and I don't think the author knew about Asimov and got the idea from him. Though it is of course a possibility. Anyway, it is not a space opera, it takes place in France. It is more a social satyre than anything else, and the only SF aspect is this supercomputer, way above the technology of that time. And also, IIRC, at the very end, a different supercomputer is mentioned, able to do something else that was SF then (maybe not anymore, since I forgot what it was).
But I believe it is enough to make my story "on-topic".

A machine "understanding" text (or anything) is still SF (science fantasy) and always will be.

Also, for people born in 1942, the 60's to 70's do not look that long after 1942. At least, looked back from now.

@FrançoisJurain  I meant, for someone not born in 1942, but rather, who was reading Asimov in 1942, 60's or 70's was SF. Computers even in the early 60's were certainly more efficient than Turing's "bombs" in Bletchley Park. Besides, Asimov certainly did not know how far Turing had advanced. Top Secret.

Well, in retrospect the 60's-70's look all the nearer to 1942 to people who were reading SF in 1942. Not quite earnest about all this by the way, in case you wondered.

Could it be this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186923/28516

@OrganicMarble No, not at all. It was in French. And none of the details match. Not motivated by a divorce.
