A programmer developed a program to read contracts and convert them to plain speech or make them abstruse
Programmer for a company writes a program for simplifying government contracts into plain speech so anyone could understand it. The software could also reverse it and make text abstruse. I think the government grabbed it and classified it top secret. I don't remember the outcome actually.
I read this about 40 years ago, I think in a Norton anthology.

Was it called ChatGPT? :-)

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

@Randal'Thor It reminds me of an aside from, IIRC, the Mueller-Fokker Effect, where a character describes a novel form of AI he developed.  Instead of inputting data and reasoning to arrive at a conclusion, you input data and a conclusion and it infers the reasoning needed to get there (also a little like ChatGPT in fact).  Nobody ever heard of it (in the book) because the US federal government bought all the rights.

@CristobolPolychronopolis: Dirk Gently’s Holistic Detective Agency by Douglas Adams, as described in the first paragraph of  https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg23130900-700-rage-against-the-machine-why-computers-need-to-argue-with-us/

@straycat Ah, yeah, I read that about the same time.  Thanks for the correction.

Slightly OT, but NPR had a segment on how the government is classifying documents to the extreme.  Buried in this segment is a bit about a researcher(?) who suggested using modern "AI" software to reduce cost/effort etc, but was shut down because that wasn't what was wanted.  The complete segment is Is the U.S. government designating too many documents as 'classified'?

@straycat - First thing I thought of. But of course I don't think that's OP's answer. This method of reasoning is quite common in human beings as well. Its what I like to call The Unscientific Method: Start with an unchangeable conclusion you want and go selectively find yourself "evidence" that can be massaged into pointing that direction.

This reminded me of a part in Asmiov's Foundation, where Salvor Hardin had a treaty and analysed to conclude that Anacreon was essentially independent from the Empire, and multiple days' worth of discussion analysed to determine that the Empire would do nothing to help the Foundation.

This sounds like "The Language Clarifier" by Paul J. Nahin, published in Omni, May 1979 and reprinted in The Best of Omni Science Fiction number 2.
The protagonist originally invents the clarifier to understand his divorce papers, but it ends up being completely taken over by the U.S. defence department to obfuscate their budget requests.

I think this is available at the Internet Archive, so I'll try to pull some quotes when I'm not on mobile.

If so, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186923/man-invents-legalese-to-english-translator/212687#212687
